# Why ErrorBoundary does not work in React, when we try to render something invalid as its children?

Tags: reactjs, react-error-boundary

I use the same `ErrorBoundary` from React [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/error-boundaries.html).

```
class ErrorBoundary extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { hasError: false };
  }

  static getDerivedStateFromError(error) {
    // Update state so the next render will show the fallback UI.
    return { hasError: true };
  }

  componentDidCatch(error, errorInfo) {
    // You can also log the error to an error reporting service
    //logErrorToMyService(error, errorInfo);
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.hasError) {
      // You can render any custom fallback UI
      return <h1>Something went wrong.</h1>;
    }

    return this.props.children; 
  }
}
```

And I intentionally try to render a simple JSX variable:

```
const JsxVariable = <div>Hi</div>
```

```
<ErrorBoundary>
    <JsxVariable />
</ErrorBoundary>
```

But the whole app crashes.

Why it does not catch the error?

Here's a live [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vibrant-saha-ntl1sw?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: `JsxVariable` is not a react component it's a rendered object, pass it as `<ErrorBoundary>{JsxVariable}</ErrorBoundary>`?

Comment: @IainShelvington, that's exactly the point here. Shouldn't error boundary catch errors? Shouldn't it tell me that it has invalid children?

Comment: The error is originating from `App` because you are trying to use something that is not a component in the jsx in the return method, `App` is not a child of `ErrorBoundary` so it doesn't catch the error

Comment: @IainShelvington Put the `App` inside an `ErrorBoundary` and you still see this error. Still the entire app crashes.

Answer (score 0):

I changed your JsxVariable component to

```
import React from "react";

export default function JsxVariable() {
  return <div>Hi</div>;
}
```

and now it's working: https://codesandbox.io/s/inspiring-hypatia-ywigtt

Comment: I know it workd with a real React component. I wonder why it does not work with JSX variables? Nowhere in the docs it's mentioned that it can not handle this error. I receive these components from different places and some of them are not in standard mode.

Comment: Please edit your title and question, as it is not clear, what you try to achive. "Error Boundary doesn't work in React" is too general.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. But I have explicitly provided a simple example of its failure, and you have fixed the bug and tell me it works. I think misunderstanding comes from your part.

Comment: What I mean is: You telling Error Boundaries are not working properly, but they do. You have a special case here.

Comment: I updated the questions's title. Is it ok now?